# Force Custom Event Handler First

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events, event-handling, addhandler

When I create custom handlers like:

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
    Public Sub AddHandlers()
        AddHandler Form1.MouseMove, AddressOf MoveMouse
    End Sub
    Private Sub MoveMouse(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Needs to happen first.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need MoveMouse in this class to fire before any other event when the user moves their mouse over Form1.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    MsgBox("Needs to happen second.")
End Sub
```

While writing this, I realized I could create yet another custom event handler in Form1's class, but is there any other way to ensure that MoveMouse (regardless of what class it is in) happens before Form1_MouseMove?

Thanks-
*~Nic*

Comment: You are adding a handler to the same event - 2 handlers for the same event which is pointless - just add code to the existing event.  Note that `AddHandler` adds a handler (!)  so the one already there will fire first.

Comment: I know. This is assuming there is a reason to have 2 handlers. I'm planning to make an application extension file which will handle certain events from the form but require them to fire first.

Comment: I have no idea what an 'application extension' is but events are private to the form other parts of the same app are not even aware of them: `Private Sub MoveMouse(...)`

Comment: I want to create a DLL file which will customize the way the user interacts with the form. It's merely a practice project using a few things I've learned and to hopefully learn more things on the way.

Comment: `Sub MoveMouse` would not exist in `Class Form1`, it would be written in the other project I am working on. This is example code but I thought my question was fairly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are fired in the order in which they are declared:

So if you want your custom class to raise `MouseMove` on Form1 before Form1 raises the event you need to make your custom class add the handler first:

```
Public Class CustomClass
    Public Sub OnMouseMoved(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Custom mouse moved")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Public Custom As CustomClass
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Custom = New CustomClass
        AddHandler MouseMove, AddressOf Custom.OnMouseMoved
        AddHandler MouseMove, AddressOf OnMouseMoved
 End Sub

    Private Sub OnMouseMoved(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Form1 mouse moved")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm looking for, but more just reassurance that there's no other factors at play than simply the order of `AddHandler` you use.

Comment: @NinjaNic : Not really, no. It more or less [**combines**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c(v=vs.110).aspx) the delegates (event handlers) as you add them, thus making the first one you added getting called first.